# Excel outer border around two rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
ID        Date         Code     Price
9202188   04/11/2014   212015   29,47
                       212026   30,5
9202190   03/11/2014   813012   99,47
                       814027   60,5
```

I have this data in an Excel file (as an example). Each row starts with an ID number and can have multiple codes associated with it. (I got this data from an old website, roughly in this format).

So in this example, ID 9202188 has 2 codes with 2 prices on 1 date, and this is one grouped item, so to speak.

I'm now trying to have Excel make an outer border around the whole group, like this:

```
ID        Date         Code     Price
______________________________________
|9202188   04/11/2014   212015   29,47|
|_______________________212026___30,5_|
|9202190   03/11/2014   813012   99,47|
|_______________________814027___60,5_|
```

Can this be automated for a list of say 200 groups of items (each containing at least 2 or more rows, but always only 1 ID number)?

I then also need to be able to sort the groups by ID while keeping the rows together, but that's another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This macro should get you the borders you want.

```
Sub wrap_border()
    Dim r As Long, br As Long, lColumns_Wide As Long, lColumn_With_Solid_Data As Long
    lColumns_Wide = 17
    lColumn_With_Solid_Data = 16
    With ActiveSheet
        For r = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, lColumn_With_Solid_Data).End(xlUp).Row
            If CBool(Len(.Cells(r, 1).Value)) Then
                If CBool(Len(.Cells(r + 1, 1).Value)) Then
                    br = r
                ElseIf CBool(Application.CountA(.Cells(r + 1, 1).Resize(Rows.Count - r, 1))) Then
                    br = .Cells(Rows.Count, lColumn_With_Solid_Data).End(xlUp).Row
                    br = Application.Evaluate("MIN(INDEX(ROW(" & (r + 1) & ":" & br & ")+NOT(LEN(A" & (r + 1) & ":A" & br & "))*1E+99,,))")
                Else
                    br = .Cells(Rows.Count, lColumn_With_Solid_Data).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                End If
                .Cells(r, 1).Resize(br - r, lColumns_Wide).BorderAround ColorIndex:=13, Weight:=xlThick
            End If
        Next r
    End With
End Sub
```

After running it on your worksheet you can expect results similar to the following.

[image: BorderAround VBA]

The parameters for modifying the style of border with `.BorderAround` can be found at [Range.BorderAround Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197210(v=office.15).aspx). Remember that you can use `Color:=` or `ColorIndex:=` but not both. I find `ColorIndex` easier to work with so long as you can get away with using the limited palette. Here is a ColorIndex table to choose from.

[image: ColorIndex Table]

As far as your sorting is concerned, you will have to fill in the blank cells in column A or use a *Helper column* off to the right to assist in keeping the values together.

*Modification:* I've added additional functionality so that the width of the border region can be set. This requires that one of the columns that has no blank cells also be identified. See lines 2 & 3 in the revised code.

Comment: I'm pasting information that is 16 columns wide, so I changed the number 4 to 16.
If I want to have the border extend to column 17 (which has no data in it whatsoever), how would I achieve this?

If I change the number to 17, the macro won't run, sadly.

Comment: @KimVandeWalle - I've added the functionality you require. The code needs to know at least one column that does not have blank cells in order to determine the extents of the data. By setting this to the blank column, the routine saw no data at all. Please review the placement of the two variables I've added to observe their functionality.

Comment: This seems to indeed work. If 'lColumn_With_Solid_Data' is equal to or higher than 15, it gives an overflow error. But i can make it work with 14. Thank you very much!

Comment: @KimVandeWalle - you may have a rogue entry somewhere but I could not even start to locate the problem without seeing the full data that is causing the problem. Glad to hear it is working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial solution using conditional formatting

=NOT(ISBLANK(B2))

=ISBLANK(B2)

[image]